# Access violation writing location 0x00000079 when running code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sfml, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to create a simple snake game as an easy first project using SFML in c++, however the program crashes.

I tried redoing all configurations in visual studio and I have tried debugging using stacker. (Don't know how to use it properly so didn't go to well.)

Here is my code:

```
#include <SFML/Window.hpp> //Loads SFML Windowfile

using namespace std; //Includes sf for Window and VideoMode

int main()
{
    Window window(VideoMode(500,500), "My window"); //Creates a window and assigns it a size and name
        return 0; 
}
```

I have also tried this code with no success:

```
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::Window window;
    window.create(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "My window");

    return 0;
}
```

I expect to get a window that is 500 x 500 pixels but instead I get this error message: "Unhandled exception at 0x000B3062 in Snake3.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000079." and it points me to xmemmory0.

[Here's the callstack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbZ9T.png)

Comment: Compile in debug mode and show us the call stack

Comment: I'm not familiar with this library, but a quick look around tells me that `VideoMode` expects the actual hardware resolution of the display as arguments, it's not the size of the window. That is set with `window.setSize` after it's created. Try following their tutorials.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError what the OP does looks OK to me, see: https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/window-window.php

Comment: @Jabberwocky I tried copying over the exact code from there before posting here. Thanks for trying to help though.

Comment: Were your `sfml` binaries built for Visual Studio 2015 or greater? Are you using debug mode binaries in your debug mode application?

Comment: @drescherjm I'm using binaries for visual studio 2017 so I don't think that is the problem. As for if I'm using debug binaries in my debug application, I'm not sure. I followed SFML's official guide and then pasted the files from the bin folder from the SFML folder into my project folder. So I think I did it right.

Comment: You can get this problem if in debug mode you use release binaries (or vice versa). There should be different binaries for debug and release.